# Issues installing Plotly Dash for R

Tags: r, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-dashr

I'm trying to install the newly released Plotly Dash package for R as described on plotly website https://dashr.plot.ly/installation, i.e. running

```
 library(devtools) # devtools: Tools to Make Developing R Packages Easier
 # The following statement will also install dashCoreComponents,     
 # dashHtmlComponents, and dashTable
 install_github('plotly/dashR') # The core dash backend
```

This is what it returns, 'unknown package' any help much appreciated

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
HTTP error 403.
API rate limit exceeded for 86.134.113.102. (But here's the good news: 
Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the 
documentation for more details.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed the package to reproduce the error, unfortunately can't be able to reproduce it. However, a potential solution along  "**error 403** and
**API rate limit exceeded ...**" could be to add your `github` authorization token in your `.Rprofile` and that is what the "**But here's the good news:**" message inside the bracket is trying to inform you. Have a look at the actual project `github` site [Dash for R](https://github.com/plotly/dashR#dash-for-r) if you haven't already. That might as well provide you an input to solving the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you manage to install it correctly as per Plotly's instruction above? I have only installed packages from CRAN but will look into this. Thanks.

Comment: @wit Yes, indeed.

Comment: Just in case you run into `is not writable` errors along the way, make sure you install the package somewhere you have write privilege (recommended) or run `R` or `Rstudio` as an admin user (not recommended).

Comment: It turns out I just didn't have some dash dependencies installed, READ.ME specifies those `install.packages(c("fiery", "routr", "reqres", "htmltools", "base64enc", "plotly", "mime", "crayon", "devtools"))`, it worked well with the required packages in place.